# Javascript replace hypen with slash

Tags: javascript, asp.net, .net, visual-studio-2008

How to replace a hypen (`-`) with a slash (`\`) in Javascript?

for example, I need to replace

> C-MyDocuments-VisualStudio2008-MyProjects

with

> C\MyDocuments\VisualStudio2008\MyProjects

I tried replace function such as `variable.replace("-","\")` but it showed me error of unterminated string constant.

I am working in VS 2008.

Comment: Peeve of mind, but please learn... "/" is slash, and "\" is *back*slash.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to escape the slash with an additional backslash like this:

```
variable = variable.replace("-","\\");
```

To replace the hyphen globally, try this:

```
variable = variable.replace(/-/g, "\\");
```

This uses a regular expression to search the string for the hyphen and the `g` modifier indicates that replacements should be global.

Comment: @@seth, @@Sarfraz, @@Andrew: I tried your solutions but it didn't worked..:-(

Comment: @@ Andrew:is any for loop like needed in JS to replace each hyphen, it replaced only first hyphen?

Comment: Good point about global replacement - I have added a solution for that as well :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
variable.replace("-","\\")
```

You need to escape the slash char.

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing with `"\\"` (two backslashes).

A single backslash escapes the following character.